# how to give authentication to folders in mvc4 application based on logged users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am developing one mvc4 application where many users will upload their documents and later they can view their documents. I am storing all documents in UploadedFile folder inside the solution folder. this is the below path to view the document. Lets say
http://192.168.012.23:8053/UploadedFile/C3kycDMS20160721141108.pdf

If user type above url document will be displayed in browser. Now the problem is any user is view the files by changing file name. So how to secure it? documents should be viewed to only those who has uploaded their file? is this possible to achieve in mvc4?

Comment: I googled and found below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367037/handling-file-permissions-on-runtime-using-mvc4 How to implement in my scenario? I am storing files inside uploadedfile folder. For ex, if user a has uploaded file1 then when the user 1 has logged in he should be abl to view only he uploaded(file1) files. Anyone suggest me how to implement this?